# Using i.a. inside parentheses to highlight something

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations

I’m writing headlines for a digest. One of my rules is to keep the headlines short, but information-dense. The following examples describe one pattern that I use regularly.

Example 1:

> Building a “CSS 3D cube” with 3D transforms (i.a. how to calculate the perspective)

Example 2:

> @kaycebasques has published a guide to Chrome’s Animation Inspector (i.a. how to interpret the chart)

Example 3:

> A complete guide to controlling the Referer header (i.a. setting a referrer policy)

I hope, these examples make it clear what I’m trying to achieve. In a nutshell, the first part of the headline provides a terse description of the resource, while the part in parentheses highlights an interesting part of that resource. I use i.a. to convey “among other things, the resource contains this interesting part:”.

My question is whether or not I’m using i.a. correctly in this context. I know that incl. is an alternative, but it seems more restrictive, e.g. “(incl. setting a referrer policy)” seems wrong. What format would you recommend?

Comment: `i.a.`, as an abbreviation for *inter alia*, is rarely used and not apt to be recognized by the majority of your readers.  If you intend *inter alia* you should spell it out.

Comment: @HotLicks I’ll make sure that my readers know what it means. Don’t worry about that.

Comment: ... When? Before the headline? HotLicks is essentially saying 'It's not ungrammatical, but that's about the only good thing you can say about it.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In the site’s FAQ :) Note that my question is about whether or not I’m using i.a. correctly, i.e. are my examples grammatically correct.

Comment: 'Acceptability' in English usage is ill-defined. Quirk and Svartvik proposed a 5-point scale of 'acceptability' in grammar from 'totally unacceptable to 99.9% of Anglophones' to 'totally acceptable to 99.9% of Anglophones' (or similar; you get the picture, I hope). Style can be at least as important as grammaticality. So, I'd say that using i.a. is more unacceptable than acceptable (though not ungrammatical). I have even found one style guide advising the dropping of such widely used abbreviations as etc and eg (though these are licensed by frequency of use and familiarity).

Comment: This is hardly ever used nowadays, whether you are writing for the general public or an academic audience.  If you do write it, it should appear in full and in italics, and even then I'd only ever suggest once (at most!) in a document.  If the part in brackets is absolutely essential then I'd probably write 'including/includes' in full.

Comment: @rhm The thing is, my headlines are restricted to a single fixed-width line, so something like “including” is out of the question. I could go with incl. instead of i.a., but as I’ve said in my question, it seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

*The Chicago Manual of Style* recommends a comma after abbreviations such as e.g., i.e., and others, prior to giving your explanation or example.

Thus, in answer to your question, I do not believe you are using it right. I'll add headlines RARELY use parentheses primarily because every word in a headline is essential and not an aside. Your examples don't seem stylistically advantageous even if you add the commas.